# How to validate OAuth 2.0 token granted by Microsoft AD using python?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory

I'm planning to create a simple web service using python in the backend that can use Azure AD for OAuth2 login.
Microsoft's documentation about logging the user in in browser and getting the token from auhentication is pretty clear in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow

However there is no mention about the validation of the token on the server side. Do I have to call HTTP api to the authorization endpoint with some parameters or can the token be validated easily without sending it to Microsoft's servers? I'm lost with this and I don't seem to find any information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the token into JWT format and need to validate the signature and the claims of the token. Please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-the-signature).

> To validate an id_token or an access_token, your app should validate
> both the token's signature and the claims. To validate access tokens,
> your app should also validate the issuer, the audience, and the
> signing tokens. These need to be validated against the values in the
> OpenID discovery document. For example, the tenant-independent version
> of the document is located at
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration.